# Can I overwrite a <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which contains data. I would like when a user clicks on the div, it to be overwritten with the contens of a file and the original content (hello) goes away, is this possible? example code below:

```
<a href="#"><div class="test">hello</div></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.test').load('/new_file.php {cookieId:"<? echo $cookieId; ?>"});
    </script>
```

So  the `<div>` with class test is a link and when it is clicked it is overwritten with contents of the file new_file.php

Is my logic correct or needs to be re-worked?

If this is possible then what would be the `<a>` onclick command to fire it?

Comment: Yes it is possible. See http://api.jquery.com/click/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: What happened when you tried your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One line:

```
<div class="test" onclick="$(this).load('/new_file.php?cookieId=<? echo $cookieId; ?>');">hello</div>
```

Though why are you sending the cookieId as a parameter?  Isn't it already being sent automatically as, well, a cookie?

Comment: You're missing the `cookieId`.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is add a click handler to your div and go grab some fresh HTML over XHR within the click handler.

Then just set the textContent with the responseText from the XHR.

```js
div.addEventListener('click', updateContent);

function updateContent() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener('load', overwriteContent);
  xhr.open('GET', '/new_file.php');
  xhr.send();

  function overWriteContent() {
    div.textContent = this.responseText;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').click(function() {
     $(this).empty().load('/new_file.php', {cookieId:"<? echo $cookieId; ?>"});
  }
}
```

Comment: .load will empty the div before loading the new content. you don't need .empty() there.

Comment: The key there is after.  Not emptying it gives no indication that it is loading something.  I generally set the text to "loading..." or something.  Didn't bother here.

Answer (score 0):

That code has an unterminated string.  Also `#test` means id 'test', whereas `.test` means class 'test'.

```
 $('.test').load('/new_file.php', {cookieId:"<? echo $cookieId; ?>"});
```

---

I hope you aren't sending that PHP to the server like that.  It's a huge security problem letting the user run any code on your server they like.  If you can do that with JS; they can do any other code they like, likely malicious.